# jsoup extracting a value of an element in tag

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am new to Jsoup. I am trying to extract a series of value for a variable "y".
I have a html like this:

```
<text class="price label" font-family="Dosis" font-size="12px" font-weight="800" fill="white" text-anchor="middle" x="49" y="408.0421247847397">5,24</text>

<text class="price label" font-family="Dosis" font-size="12px" font-weight="800" fill="white" text-anchor="middle" x="122" y="412.832428136177">5,11</text>
```

I want to extract the values of y i.e, 408.0421247847397, 412.832428136177 and the value after the attribute and before tag,i.e., 5.24,5,11.

Could you please suggest me a way?

I am able to extract only the first value of y(408.0421247847397). But not the second value(412.832428136177). Also I am unable to extract the title 5.24 and 5.11. I have done :

```
doc1 =Jsoup.parse(input,"UTF-8", "");
Elements values = doc1.select("g");
Elements xyz = doc1.select("text.price.label");
String abc = xyz.attr("y");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of `select` is `Elements` (plural) class which `extends ArrayList<Element>`. This class allows us to use some methods designed for single `Element` to let us access values from one (first) selected element. It is helpful when there is only one element selected.

But if used query found more `Element`s which you want to access you will need to iterate over query result (here `Elements xyz`). To do so you can use loop like

```
for (Element el :  xyz ){
    String yAttr = el.attr("y"); //get value of `y` attribute
    String text = el.text();     //get text which browser should show for this element
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pshemo. It worked :) Is there a way where I can store all these values in an array and accessing one by one later ? Can I use a list or arrayList  for this?

Comment: Yes, you can create `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>()` before loop and `list.add(whatYouWant)` inside loop.

Comment: Thank you so much. As I am new to Java, this was very helpful